# How to define two fields of two generic types with the same type in typescript?

Tags: typescript

Suppose I have a function which need to use two generic types:

```
function foo<
  T, 
  R, 
  KL extends keyof T, 
  KR extends keyof R
>(lft: T, rgh: R, kl: KL, kr: KR): void;
```

How I can I ensure that `T[KL]` and `R[KR]` with the same type?

For example.

```
const obj1 = {id: 1, name: "foo"};
const obj2 = {oid: 2, score: 98}

foo(obj1, obj2, 'id', 'oid'); // ok
foo(obj1, obj2, 'name', 'oid'); // compile failed for obj1['name'] and obj2['oid'] with diff types
```

Comment: Awesome! That's exactly what I want, would you explain more in the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [constrain](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) `R` so that it must be assignable to `Record<KR, T[KL]>`, using [the `Record` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type) to say that the property at `R[KR]` must be assignable to `L[KL]`.  Like this:

```
declare function foo<
  T,
  R extends Record<KR, T[KL]>,
  KL extends keyof T,
  KR extends keyof R
>(lft: T, rgh: R, kl: KL, kr: KR): void;
```

Yes, that's a recursive constraint, since `R` depends on `KR` and `KR` depends on `R`, but it happens to be one of the forms of circularity TypeScript supports.  Let's see how it works:

```
const obj1 = { id: 1, name: "foo" };
const obj2 = { oid: 2, score: 98 }

foo(obj1, obj2, 'id', 'oid'); // ok
foo(obj1, obj2, 'name', 'oid'); // error!
// -----> ~~~~
// Argument of type '{ oid: number; score: number; }' is not assignable to 
// parameter of type 'Record<"oid", string>'. Types of property 'oid' 
// are incompatible.
```

Looks good!  The first call succeeds because `{oid: string, score: number}` is assignable to `Record<"oid", number>`, while the second one fails because it is not assignable to `Record<"oid", string>`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtVJxwB4AoeeAFQBoz4AleEADwxFWAGd7wcZgiA0nSqUA2gIAyAXQB8NcpMYs2neAGsQATxyJK8+EKWt2XDdt10SMgBQREGAFx74MAOYALJ8PUQnkkWowfnQAlE4AbjhYwADcJCRgeBwY8DgARgBWAIzwALzwAN7w0U5ZIqhQALYgTgBEiIS18AC+cYmoyamZAEx5hakl8N0iHIlwTgCcABwt8Q041unZIkvD8ADk0esi61HA6yEx8AD0x6lqJPOLmWVdGWvrFdXbG3sHR6eMMDC8AIQknwAtMDgTJ4AA-SHggFnACCbmQ1VQKR08AwmgADgh1kU9k5UIi0iAYEdRrwavACZUiSSWutilxUDgUlAOBwsK4KmkIAgMDh4DD4BjYFUQKwYKldOisRs6Dw+ERantaiMMDAsKhXDJ1gA6SiYkBcVEYn5YmDo15bAWfWAIDWJSrC7DckA6khAA)